# Is the proof is correct?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Is it correct?

```
p → q, ¬p → r, ¬q → ¬r ⊢ q

1) p -> q    premise
2) ¬p → r    premise
3) ¬q → ¬r  premise
4) ¬q         assumption 
5) ¬p         MT 1,4 
6) r         e2   2,5 
7)  ¬q       assumption
8) ¬r         e2 3,7
9) ⊥          ¬e 6,8
10 ¬q        assumption
11) q          ¬e 9, 10
```

I believe it is true. Could you please help?